# A question regarding a discrete sub-space

Tags: general-topology

denote by $A$ the set $\{\frac{1}{n}  \,\, |\,\,\,  n\in N \}$. Is $A$ a discrete sub-space of $\mathbb{R}$? (with the standard topology)

I was told that it is, but I think it isn't. For example, the set $\{ \frac{1}{2} \}$ should be open in the relative topology (assuming $A$ is discrete), but there is no open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\{ \frac{1}{2} \} = A\cap U$, or am I missing one?

Comment: what about $(3/7 , 4/7)$? This is an open interval containing 1/2, and no other points are in $A$.

Comment: @AlfredYerger

Yes, you are correct. My bad, I mistook $A$ for being all the $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$. Now it's obvious $A$ is a discrete sub-space. As for my "mistaken" $A$, i.e. the set $B=\{ \frac{a}{b} \,\, | \,\,\, a,\, b \in \mathbb{N} \}$, it isn't a discrete sub-space, right? Now I can take $\frac{1}{2} $ and there is no such open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ so that $A\cap U = \{ \frac{1} {2} \}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence is monotonically decreasing, $a_n = {1 \over n}$ obeys $a_{n+1} < a_{n}$ for all $n$. So a neighbourhood of $a_n, n \ge 1$ that misses all other points of the sequence is $(a_{n+1}, a_{n-1})$, where we define $a_0 = 2$ for convenience.

In general in a Hausdorff space $X$, if we have a convergent sequence $(a_n)$ with all distinct elements, and its limit is $a$, which is not equal to any of the $a_n$, then the set $A = \{a_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is discrete: suppose $a_k$ is a point of the sequence, and let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint neighbourhoods of $a$ and $a_k$ respectively. Then $F = A \setminus (U \cap A)$ is a finite set, as $a$ is the limit of the sequence, so all but finitely many $a_m$ are in $U$. So $F$ is closed (and contains $a_k$), so $V \setminus (F \setminus \{a_k\})$ is open in $X$, and intersects $A$ only in $\{a_k\}$.